# Sending big responses with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, webserver, imap

I am implementing a little webmail with a rails backend that talks with an IMAP server. The problem is that when I retrieve some raw data, if the attachment is big (even 6/7 mb) it take so much time to webrick to send it.

How can I improve the performance of sending "big data"? Is there a more suited webserver?

(I haven't tried the other yet, because I am yet in the early stages of development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webrick is definitely not the best web server out of there. Most Rails applications uses a combination of a front-end proxy (generally Nginx or Apache) and a back-end Rack-compatible web server (such as Unicorn, Puma, Passenger, etc.).

What you may want to do is to avoid the data being sent by the Ruby process, otherwise Ruby may have to load the file in memory. For example, you can pass have Nginx serving the file directly using the [Rack send-file](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Sendfile.html) feature that is also supported in Rails using `send_file`.

Comment: Can you link a tutorial of something where I can learn how to use it. Can I use even if I have not the file, but the blob(base 64 econded)

Comment: I don't have an explicit tutorial. I posted you a link to the Rack documentation. You can start from there and search for more details if it's not enough.

Comment: I am a newbie with concept, so I have studied your solutions, and it turns out to be the best! thanks